# SWT: better to use methods for new display.shell?

Tags: java, shell, methods, swt

I've been initializing my SWT shells entirely inside the main method as follows:

```
public class MySWTTemplate;
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Display display = new display();

    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setSize(250, 250);
    Rectangle bds = getMonitor().getBounds();
    Point p = shell.getSize();
    int xPos = (bds.width - p.x) / 2;
    int yPos = (bds.height - p.y) / 2;
    shell.setBounds(xPos, yPos, p.x, p.y);

    shell.open();
    while(!shell.isDisposed()){
      if(!display.readAndDispatch()){
        display.sleep();
      }

    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

But I've seen some people set it up so that the shell initiation and definition are in their own method, while the cell positioning on the screen when launched is in another and both are called simply through the main method.  I took as stab at this and came up with the following:

```
public class MySWTTemplate;
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Display display = new Display();
    new MySWTTemplate(display);
    display.didpose();
  }

 public MySWTTemplate(Display display){
   Shell shell = new Shell(display);
   shell.setSize(250, 250);
   shellPos(shell);

   shell.open();
   while(!shell.isDisposed()){
     if(!display.readAndDispatch()){
       display.sleep()
     }
   }
 }

 public void shellPos(Shell shell){
   Rectangle bds = shell.getMonitor().getBounds();
   Point p = shell.getSize();
   int xPos = (bds.width - p.x) / 2;
   int yPos = (bds.height - p.y) / 2;
   shell.setBounds(xPos, yPos, p.x, p.y);
 }
```

Both work.  My two questions are

1)  is this done simply for visual organization, or does calling separate methods for each job offer a resource benefit?

2)  Can someone explain in the second code what is happening when the MySWTTemplate() method is created and then simply called with "new MySWTTemplate(display)" in the main method?  Why is the method named exactly as the class is?  And what is this fundamentally saying (you can't set this method as just public with any other method name.

Answer (score 2):

1. This is simply for code organization. Of course, it's more useful when it avoids duplicating code (e.g. because you need to open several shells and position them in a similar way).
2. This isn't a *method*, but a *constructor* of the `MySWTTemplate` class. If you don't know what constructors are, you should consider reading a good Java book or a tutorial, since you may be missing other equally basic things as well.

Comment: Thanks... and will do. I remember constructors and i will refresh myself.  In the meantime can you explain why 'public MySWTTemplate (Display display)' is not a method and 'public void shellPos(Shell shell)' is a method?  Unless I'm wrong in calling shellPos a method.  Also, 'public static void main(String[] args) is considered a method correct?

Comment: Constructor has the same name as the class and no return type (and is called with `new`). Method has a return type (`void` in the case of `shellPos`). `main` is a method, yes. More precisely a _static_ method (it belongs to the entire class instead of objects of this class).

Comment: So static specifies that a method can be used class-wide.  Whereas leaving the modifier out completely allows it to be accessed only by a specific object within the class?

Comment: It can be accessed _by_ any object (since it's `public`). But it can only be called _on_ a specific object _of_ this class. I.e. if you have `MySWTTemplate template = ...;` somewhere, you can call `template.shellPos(...)`.